# How to extract the last part of the string in Excel after the last underscore

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following example data:

```
1. animated_brand_300x250
2. animated_brand_300x600
3. customaffin_greenliving_solarhome_anim_outage_offer
```

How to extract the string from the last underscore in Microsoft Excel?

I want to extract the value before the first underscore and after the last underscore.

First underscore:

```
=LEFT(B6,SEARCH(“_”,B6)-1)
```

would return `animated` and `customaffin` as output.

How to return the string after the last underscore?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find the string after the last `_` using the `RIGHT` function. The tricky part is to find the position of the last `_`.

First, we need to determine, how many `_` there are. This can be done be removing all `_` and compare the length of both strings:

```
LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1;"_";""))
```

Since we now know that it is the second occurrence of _ that we have to look for, we can use the `SUBSTITUTE` function to replace the second occurrence of `_` with another character (this has to be a character that is not part of your original string - I have chosen`#`).

Now, we use the `FIND` function to search for the position of the `#` character. This position can now be delivered to the `RIGHT` function.

**Your final formula will be:**

```
=RIGHT(A1;LEN(A1)-FIND("#";SUBSTITUTE(A1;"_";"#";LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1;"_";"")));1))
```

[image: Get the last string after a character with multiple occurrrences in Excel]

Comment: I just had to change ; to , for it to works. Thank you!

Comment: @GerhardPowell Correct, depending on your Windows regional settings, you might need to use either comma `,` or colon `;` as list separator.

Comment: In case you need to translate long formulas to another language, like I did in this case, you can use the handy Excel Functions Translator: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-functions-translator-f262d0c0-991c-485b-89b6-32cc8d326889

Answer (score 11):

Some other options could be:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_",REPT(" ",100)),100))
```

Or using `FILTERXML`, being theoretically a better option:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[last()]")
```

An ExcelO365 exclusive method could even be to use `XLOOKUP`:

```
=REPLACE(A1,1,XLOOKUP("_",MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1),SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),,0,-1),"")
```

Or:

```
=RIGHT(A1,MATCH("_",MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1),,LEN(A1),-1),1),0)-1)
```

Comment: Very elegant solutions - especially the XML.

Comment: @MichaelWycisk, thanks. You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194) interesting if you like to know more about `FILTERXML`.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. I actually thought that it would be possible to extract elements by position using `FILTERXML` - but only after reading your answer here.